# laravel/JS typeahead for two different input fields

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, typeahead.js

I have two fields in my form, customer name, card name, i am trying to implement autocomplete to fetch details from the database to auto fill the rest of the fields.

I have got typeahead working on the first input field, however, when using the same method for the second field which is the card number, autofill is not coming up at all. I am not sure what i am doing wrong, a little guidance is appreciated here.

here is my create.blade.php

```
      <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Customer Name:</strong>
              <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" id='cust' onkeypress="myFunction1()" placeholder="Customer Name">
            </div>
  <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Card Number:</strong>
                    <input  class="typeahead form-control" type="text" id='card' autocomplete="off" onkeypress="myFunction()" placeholder="Card Number">
                </div>
<script>
        function myFunction() {
          var path = "{{ route('autocompletecard') }}";
          $('#card').typeahead({
              source:  function (query, process) {
              return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {

                      return process(data);
                  });
              }
          });
        }
        function myFunction1()
        {
          var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
          $('#cust').typeahead({
              source:  function (query, process) {
              return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                      return process(data);
                  });
              }
          });
        }
        </script>
```

here is my Assignee controller:

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
          {
              $data = Customer::select("name")
                      ->where("name","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
                      ->get();

              return response()->json($data);
          }
          public function autocompletecard(Request $request)
              {
                  $data = Card::select("number")
                          ->where("number","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
                          ->get();

                  return response()->json($data);
              }
```

after checking the console and network tab on the browser autocompletecard is being executed, it is returning a card number as response. but it is not showing as autocomplete.

Comment: maybe because `autocomplete="off"` in your second input?

Comment: Hi, no autocomplete is used to disable the computer default auto complete options, typeahead official tutorials suggests to turn it off.